# Read Local HTML File using WinHTTPRequest

Tags: excel, vba, winhttprequest

I am trying the following code

```
Sub myConSP()
    Dim oHtmlSP As HTMLDocument
    Dim tSPIndex As HTMLDivElement
    Dim tSPIdx As HTMLDivElement
    Dim tables As Object
    
    Set oHtmlSP = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Test.html", False
        .send
        oHtmlSP.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set tables = oHtmlSP.querySelectorAll("table[width='100%'] table:first-child")
    Debug.Print tables.Length
End Sub
```

I tried different ways to read the HTML local file through that code. How can I refer to the local file HTML file in such a code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things.

Try:

```
Sub myConSP()
    Dim oHtmlSP As HTMLDocument

Set oHtmlSP = New HTMLDocument
oHtmlSP.body.innerHTML = "full_path"

'process the file
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't complicate things but tries to solve another problem in a different way. Using your approach, and tried that `Set tables = oHtmlSP.querySelectorAll("table[width='100%'] table:first-child")` Then when trying to display the length `Debug.Print tables.Length` I got null as a result. You can have a look at this url http://try.jsoup.org/~LsArJXLumBWg2HOgluVzOXm9bRs

Comment: @YasserKhalil glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This approach solved the problem. I have used late binding as for the variable `html` and this is important as when using the early binding, I got invalid use of NULL as for the property of tables length.

```
Sub NewTest()
    Dim fStream As Object, html As Object, tables As Object, sFolder As String, sFile As String

    sFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sFile = "Test.html"
  
    Set fStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set html = CreateObject("HtmlFile")

    With fStream
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile sFolder & sFile
        html.body.innerHTML = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
  
    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("table[width='100%'] table:first-child")
    Debug.Print tables.Length
End Sub
```

Comment: This solved the problem at this link too (a nother question related to that question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66983813/css-selector-invalid-use-of-null-tables-length-property